# How to update Customer Order in Magento 1.9.3.1

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, sales-order, invoice, creditmemo

Customer purchased Product X. We shipped Product Y. Now I want remove Product X and add Product Y in the Sales Order or Sales Invoice.

Answer (score 1):

Do credit memo from backemd, returm to stock and ctreate new order in backend

Comment: Create a new order with Product Y for the same customer?